# Java - Access to a local variable from anonymous class

Tags: java

The problem in `found = true;` line

```
public boolean containsBlock(String nodeName, ASTNode node)
{
    boolean found = false;
    if(nodeName.equals("if"))
    {
        node.accept(new ASTVisitor()
        {
            public boolean visit(IfStatement s)
            {
                found = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return found;
}
```

I know that I will be able to access this if I make `found` a class global variable, but I don't want to do this. Maybe there is another way? I just need to let the other code know that something was found

UPD:
Is that code better and will return the right

```
public boolean containsBlock(Text nodeName, ASTNode node)
{
    final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if(nodeName.matches("if"))
            {
                node.accept(new ASTVisitor()
                {
                    public boolean visit(IfStatement s)
                    {
                        flag.set(true);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
            else
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown NodeName: " + nodeName);
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return flag.get();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  What are you actually trying to do?  I'm feeling an XY problem.

Comment: @markspace, This is the method for parsing the source code. I'm trying to detect some elements in the `ASTNode` (if statements, cycle statements , block statements and etc). What will we look depends from `nodeName`. If something was found from this in the given part of source code, we should know about it and change flag variable and return the result

Comment: @ivan your flag is useless. If the code will get executed out-of-order (which is probably the case here, since I suspect either deferred or async call here), you'll get false returned virtually all of the time (unless you have ASTNode processing in another thread, plus it'd have to be *lightning fast*, mind me). If you want the flag to work, you have to e.g. make it a persistent data, by creating an external field for it, and skipping the `return` altogether. Non-linear code (even not multithreading one, visitor pattern included) doesn't work the way synchronous, linear one does.

Comment: @ivan it'd be better if you told us *what functionality do you expect the code to provide* and *what library do you use*. Your 2nd code makes no sense for the very same reason first doesn't - the Runnable will just complete instantly, adding the visitor to the node. If you're 100% sure this is the way to achieve what you want, you should wait (block) in containsBlock() method for the notification from visit() method after accept-ing it, and then process the node's tree in another thread to trigger the visit(). I suspect there's a lot easier way to do it, but without a lib ref...

Comment: @vaxquis, I got it. I use JDT and want to get all wanted statements (which are wanted depends from `nodeName`, it might be `if`, `for`, `while` or etc statement). But I'm not ready to create a lot of classes extending `ASTVisitor`, because there are a lot of methods which are using ASTVisitor in different purposes. My choice is anonymous classes, but how wait them?

Comment: @ivan http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait() for notify in one thread , then send the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify() to the object from the other thread.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTVisitor.html See, `public abstract class ASTVisitor extends Object` it means that it processes synchronously? :)

Comment: @ivan method signature (e.g. `synchronized` keyword) only tells you if it's blocking for synchronous access by default or not; it doesn't say if it will process synchronously or not. IMO you should learn more about threading (at least https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html and other Oracle tutorials) before continuing this pursuit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are only final variables accessible in anonymous class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a `ASTVisitor` instance to the `ASTNode` instance (using the accept method), it doesn't execute your `visit` method immediately. Therefore, there's no point to attempt to change a local variable of your `containsBlock` method from within the `visit` method.

`visit` will most likely be executed after your `containsBlock` method has returned, at which point your local `found` variable will no longer be in the call stack.

Comment: Yup. This is exactly the point here IMO. Accessing outer scope for read is one thing - it can be done and is done routinely. Accessing it for write is useless unless the data can be referenced outside, which would constitute a field variable, which wouldn't need any special provisioning to be used inside anonymous.

Comment: Huh, but how to make it be executed immediately?

Comment: @ivan I'm not fimiliar with these classes, but from the Javadoc I found, `ASTNode` calls the `visit` method of the `ASTVisitor` that was passed to it when you reach the `ASTNode` instance while iterating over the tree. This is a standard visitor design pattern.